# Avoid http redirection on Apache installed on raspberry pi

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, redirect, raspbian

I want to setup a website on my raspberry pi 3 (with raspbian) to be accessible from the internet.
I installed Apache webserver (v 2.4) and Word Press, and I can connect to the website from the LAN.
To have my website accessible from the internet, I configured my router to perform forwarding of port 80 to a static IP given to the raspberry pi.

However, when i try to access the website from the internet (using the public IP 213.57.x.x), the browser is automatically redirected to the internal IP (192.x.x.x).

For me it looks like the default Apache settings (which i didn't change) perform IP forwarding.

I suspect that the Apache is the problem because I do not encounter the same problem on tomcat installed on the machine (so the router configuration is OK).